# writing text with pygame from function in seperate .py file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a program that needs to often write text on the screen on a textbox. Since I'm already using pygame for something else here and have a separate file for my functions, I thought about going about it this way. As it stands right now my code looks like this:

In the main file:

```
import mainengine as me, pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

screenSize = width, height = 1280, 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screenSize)
pygame.display.set_caption('test')

bg = pygame.image.load("test.jpg")

screen.blit(bg, [0, 0])

me.text('test', 'how do code')

pygame.display.flip()
```

Then in the secondary file:

```
def text(speaker, text):
    import pygame

    white = (255, 255, 255) 
    gray = (200, 200, 200)
    Sfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 24)
    Lfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
    tb = pygame.image.load("textbox.png")
    tbRect = tb.get_rect()
    tbRect = tbRect.move(20, 550)

    screen.blit(tb, tbRect)
    screen.blit(Sfont.render(speaker, True, gray), [tbRect.x + 10, tbRect.y + 10])
    screen.blit(Lfont.render(text, True, white), [tbRect.x + 10, tbRect.y + 35])
```

This is the error I get when I run the main file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\Stuff\Misc Misc\Python\Scripts\Game\Main\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    me.text('test', 'how do code')
  File "C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\Stuff\Misc Misc\Python\Scripts\Game\Main\mainengine.py", line 66, in text
    screen.blit(tb, tbRect)
NameError: name 'screen' is not defined
```

Putting this in a function would make the code a lot cleaner, so It'd be nice if there was a way to pull it off, chances are its not exactly what I have here. I'm not exactly the best at software development.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to add an argument for the target surface to the function:

```py
def text(surf, speaker, text):
    # [...]
```

Furthermore, do not load the image and do not recreate the [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font), every time when a text is rendered. Create the objects once at initialization. Loading a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) and creating a `pygame.font.Font` object are very time consuming operations:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
Sfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 24)
Lfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
tb = pygame.image.load("textbox.png")

def text(surf, speaker, text):

    white = (255, 255, 255) 
    gray = (200, 200, 200)
    tbRect = tb.get_rect(topleft = (20, 550))

    surf.blit(tb, tbRect)
    surf.blit(Sfont.render(speaker, True, gray), [tbRect.x + 10, tbRect.y + 10])
    surf.blit(Lfont.render(text, True, white), [tbRect.x + 10, tbRect.y + 35])
```

Pass the target surface to the function. For instance:

```py
me.text(screen, 'test', 'how do code')
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work without loading the images and fonts in the function itself but efficiency isn't a huge concern for me. All that matters is that it does write text from a function. Thanks a bunch!